# Matlab error- Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object

Tags: matlab, ms-access

Why do I get the error Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object. Below is my code. Can anybody tell me what is wrong with this code?

```
%Read data from database.
curs = exec(conn, sprintf(['SELECT   description.imageName'...
    ' , description.brand'...
    ' , description.price'...
    ' , description.size'...
    ' , description.clothingDescription'...
    ' FROM  description WHERE description.imageID ="%s"'],imagename));

curs = fetch(curs);
close(curs);

%Assign data to output variable
results = curs.Data; 
disp(results);

set(handles.edit1,'String',results{1}); 
set(handles.edit2,'String',results{2});
set(handles.edit3,'String',results{3});
set(handles.edit4,'String',results{4}); 
set(handles.edit5,'String',results{5});
```

This is the full error message

```
Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

Error in image_desc1>image_desc1_OpeningFcn (line 90)
set(handles.edit1,'String',results{1});

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 220)
    feval(gui_State.gui_OpeningFcn, gui_hFigure, [], guidata(gui_hFigure), varargin{:});

Error in image_desc1 (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
```

This is **one of the sample data** execute in command window when typing the code in

```
WHERE description.imageID =1
```

'High Neck Tee'    'ZALORA'    [40]    'S,M,L,XL'    'Blush High Neck by ZALORA'

After typing the whos, it show this sentence in command window

```
Name         Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  results      1x1                 8  double
```

Comment: Post the full error message (and read it, it will tell you exactly what the problem is) and give us some sample data so that we can run the code, as it is this question is hard to answer, more details will get you a better answer.

Comment: @David
I edited the question like what you asked for.
Thanks for repying :)

Comment: Your edit did improve the question, thanks.

Comment: @David, I should be the one who thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error communicates the message clearly as it is. The variable `results` is not a cell array and you are trying to extract non-existing `results{1},...,results{5}`. Hence the error.

Comment: Dear @Parag S. Chandakkar, 
can you teach me how to solve it? by changing the code above. thank you so much. This is because the data that I stored in the ms ACCESS database show it was a cell array.

Comment: I can't help you because of lack of information. I don't know what kind of `results` variable is? Type `whos results` in the command window after executing the line `disp(results);` and post its output in the question itself.

Comment: I have edited my question by typing whos results, it show the class is double, but why? this is because the data show it is cell-array format when typing the code in (WHERE description.imageID =1) instead of (WHERE description.imageID =%s).
Thanks for helping

Comment: So, `results` is a scalar. Just a single number.

Comment: @ Parag S. Chandakkar
Can I convert it by num2cell? 
actually when I convert it to num2cell, it display error like 
"index exceed matrix dimension"

Comment: First of all, since it is a scalar, it does not have 5 elements in it. So you can't do `results(1), results(2), ..., results(5)`. It won't matter if you convert it to a cell. It will just change a way of accessing `results`. For example, instead of `results(1)`, you will access it as `results{1}`.

Comment: @ Parag S. Chandakkar
But I put it as results{1} already instead of results(1) in my code?